# Python: appending a variable to Popen

Tags: python

When i try to carry out the code below i get the error "unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'str'"

```
from subprocess import Popen
z = '10000'
Popen(["formatdb", "-p", "T", "-i", "%s.txt"] % (z)).wait()
```

How would I insert my variable z into the name of my text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

% should immediately follow the string that's being formatted, and you don't need parens around the `z`. Like so:

```
Popen(["formatdb", "-p", "T", "-i", "%s.txt" % z]).wait()
```

Comment: You don't need the parens around z.